# keeping the continued code that will NOT fail still in try...except?

Tags: python

[Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html#d0e14928) -

This is a small snippet from `fileinfo.py` used in the book. This is opening an MP3 file and reading the last 128 bytes to fetch and later parse the metadata.

```
try:                                
  fsock = open(filename, "rb", 0) 
  try:                           
    fsock.seek(-128, 2)         
    tagdata = fsock.read(128)   
  finally:                        
    fsock.close()              
  .
  .                       # process tagdata: will NEVER raise IOError though
  .
except IOError:                     
  pass
```

This can be refactored as:

```
try:                                
  fsock = open(filename, "rb", 0) 
  try:                           
    fsock.seek(-128, 2)         
    tagdata = fsock.read(128)         
except IOError:                     
  pass
finally:
  fsock.close()              

.
.                       # process tagdata
.
```

I even used to have this question when I was learning `Java`. Should we just keep the logic that can actually raise an exception inside the `try..except` block or for the sake of keeping a code that does one particular job in ONE place; keep the other code that will NEVER raise an exception also within a `try...except`?

Comment: That second example is not valid Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `try`/`finally` clause's primary purpose is to close the file regardless of what happens, it doesn't make sense to move it the outer `try`/`except` as I assume you are trying to do:

```
try:
    fsock = open(filename, "rb", 0)
    try:
        fsock.seek(-128, 2)
        tagdata = fsock.read(128)
    except:
        pass
except IOError:
    pass
finally:
    fsock.close()
```

The reason being, if `IOError` is actually raised, calling `fsock.close()` would raise another exception, since `fsock` would not have been assigned. Instead of either, it'd be preferable to use the `with` statement which will automatically close the file for you:

```
try:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fsock:
        fsock.seek(-128, 2)
        tagdata = fsock.read(128)
except IOError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 6):

The most accepted standard is to put as little code in the try..except as possible. Reasoning is that you don't know *what* the other code will raise if there's a ton of code in a try.. then it becomes really messy.

You can see lots of good styling information in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), amongst which is:

```
- Additionally, for all try/except clauses, limit the 'try' clause
  to the absolute minimum amount of code necessary.  Again, this
  avoids masking bugs.

  Yes:

      try:
          value = collection[key]
      except KeyError:
          return key_not_found(key)
      else:
          return handle_value(value)

  No:

      try:
          # Too broad!
          return handle_value(collection[key])
      except KeyError:
          # Will also catch KeyError raised by handle_value()
          return key_not_found(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second piece of code is syntactically invalid, so you should prefer the first form.

If you'd make it syntactically valid by adding an `except` or `finally` clause, it would be semantically invalid: if the `open` fails, you'd still be trying to close `fsock`, which would not be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

If the `open` fails then you can't assign to `tagdata`, so you should not allow the code to reach the point where you process `tagdata`. Often the best way to handle this is to process the `IOError` at a higher level (i.e. wrap this in a function and handle it in the calling context).

BTW, in modern Python we don't need to use `finally` for this sort of thing - we have a more powerful idiom. We also have an `else` clause that can be attached to try/except blocks that is executed only if the exception handlers are **not** invoked.

So we get something like:

```
def get_data():
    with open(filename, "rb", 0) as fsock:
        fsock.seek(-128, 2)
        return fsock.read(128)

def do_processing():
    try: tagdata = get_data()
    except IOError: handle_error()
    else: process(tagdata)
```